# Creating a YouTube Service via ASP.NET using a pre-existing Access Token

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, youtube-api, google-oauth

I've been working on a Website for users to upload videos to a shared YouTube account for later access.  After much work I've been able to get an Active Token, and viable Refresh Token.

However, the code to initialize the `YouTubeService` object looks like this:

```
UserCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, 
        // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
        // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
        new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None
    );
}

var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name,
});
```

I've already got a token, and I want to use mine. I'm using ASP.NET version 3.5, and so I can't do an `async` call anyways.

Is there any way I can create a `YouTubeService` object without the `async` call, and using my own token? Is there a way I can build a credential object without the Authorization Broker?

Alternatively, the application used YouTube API V2 for quite some time, and had a form that took a token, and did a post action against a YouTube URI that was generated alongside the token in API V2. Is there a way I can implement that with V3? Is there a way to use Javascript to upload videos, and possibly an example that I could use in my code?

Comment: If you are using framework 3.5 then the library with async calls will not work, it should be compiled against fw 4.0 or higher...

Comment: Yep.  That is why I want a solution that doesn't rely on the async calls.  I don't want to upgrade the framework if I don't absolutely have to.

Comment: Oh my god - it's 2017 and I'm running into the same thing. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: To clarify - the same problem, but for different reasons; I'm attempting to do some of this work in the cloud where there isn't a UI. However, I should already have an access token coming in with my request.

Comment: I did figure out how to programatically initialize a UserCredential object.   I'll post my code in an answer because it is too long for a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NOTE: I ended up upgrading my Framework to 4.5 to access the google libraries.

To programatically initialize a UserCredential Object you've got to build a Flow, and TokenResponse.  A Flow Requires a Scope (aka the permissions we are seeking for the credentials.

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows;

string[] scopes = new string[] {
    YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube,
    YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload
};

GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
{
    ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
    {
        ClientId = XXXXXXXXXX,  <- Put your own values here
        ClientSecret = XXXXXXXXXX  <- Put your own values here
    },
    Scopes = scopes,
    DataStore = new FileDataStore("Store")
});

TokenResponse token = new TokenResponse {
    AccessToken = lblActiveToken.Text,
    RefreshToken = lblRefreshToken.Text
};

UserCredential credential = new UserCredential(flow, Environment.UserName, token);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You stated you are using .net 3.5 The Google .net client library works with a min of .net 4.0 which is not updated any more. .net 4.5 is the current supported target. The library is not going to work in your project. Unless you have updated the framework.  This is also not going to work because FileDatastore requires a refresh token to work and the question states access token.

Comment: As far as the initial token.  That was easy.  I built a separate form to seed that token, and then store it in a database.   When it is time to use it, I check my token expiration, and if it is expired I refresh it via the stored refresh token.

Comment: What is this lblActiveToken and this lblRefreshToken ? Are you taking those inputs from the user? I would like to use my account to retrieve list of videos from playlist.

Answer (score 4):

Currently the official [Google .NET client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client) does not work with .NET Framework 3.5. *(Note: this is an old question the library hasn't supported .NET 3.5 since 2014. So the statement would have been valid then as well.)*  That being said you are not going to be able to create a service for the Google .NET client library using an existing access token. Also not possible to create it with an access token using any .NET Framework you would need to create your own implementation of `Idatastore` and load a refresh token.

> Supported Platforms
>
> 1. .NET Framework 4.5 and 4.6
> 2. .NET Core (via netstandard1.3 support)
> 3. Windows 8 Apps
> 4. Windows Phone 8 and 8.1
> 5. Portable Class Libraries

That being said you are going to have to code this yourself from the ground up. I have done it and it is doable.

Authentication :

You have stated you have your refresh token already so I won't go into how to create that.
The following is a HTTP POST call

Refresh access token request:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token 
client_id={ClientId}.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={ClientSecret}&refresh_token=1/ffYmfI0sjR54Ft9oupubLzrJhD1hZS5tWQcyAvNECCA&grant_type=refresh_token
```

Refresh Access token response:

```
{ "access_token" : "ya29.1.AADtN_XK16As2ZHlScqOxGtntIlevNcasMSPwGiE3pe5ANZfrmJTcsI3ZtAjv4sDrPDRnQ", "token_type" : "Bearer", "expires_in" : 3600 }
```

An call you make to the YouTube API you can either add the access token as the authorization bearer token or you can just take it on to the end of any request

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?access_token={token here}
```

I have a full post on all of the calls to the auth server [Google 3 legged Oauth2 flow](http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/). I just use normal [webRequets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f(v=vs.110).aspx) for all my calls.

```
// Create a request for the URL.
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com/default.html");  
// If required by the server, set the credentials.  
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;  
// Get the response.
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();  
// Display the status.
Console.WriteLine (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);  
// Get the stream containing content returned by the server.  
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();  
// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.  
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
// Read the content.
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
// Display the content.  
Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);  
// Clean up the streams and the response.  
reader.Close();  
response.Close();
```

**Upgrade .NET 4+**

If you can upgrade to the newest version of .NET using the library will be much easier. This is from Googles official documentation [Web Applications ASP.NET](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc). I have some additional sample code on my github account which shoes how to use the Google Drive API. [Google dotnet samples YouTube data v3](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/Genreated-samples1.0/YouTube%20Data%20API/v3).

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Mvc;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;

namespace Google.Apis.Sample.MVC4
{
    public class AppFlowMetadata : FlowMetadata
    {
        private static readonly IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                {
                    ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                    {
                        ClientId = "PUT_CLIENT_ID_HERE",
                        ClientSecret = "PUT_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE"
                    },
                    Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                    DataStore = new FileDataStore("Drive.Api.Auth.Store")
                });

        public override string GetUserId(Controller controller)
        {
            // In this sample we use the session to store the user identifiers.
            // That's not the best practice, because you should have a logic to identify
            // a user. You might want to use "OpenID Connect".
            // You can read more about the protocol in the following link:
            // https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login.
            var user = controller.Session["user"];
            if (user == null)
            {
                user = Guid.NewGuid();
                controller.Session["user"] = user;
            }
            return user.ToString();

        }

        public override IAuthorizationCodeFlow Flow
        {
            get { return flow; }
        }
    }
}
```

Top tip YouTube doesn't support service accounts your going to have to stick with Oauth2. As long as you have authenticated your code once it should continue to work.

Comment: Forgot to mention - I'm actually using .NET 4.6.2. I have access to the SDK, but it seems like there's a lot of implicit behavior that I have to deal with in terms of the web request.

Comment: I have edited my answer adding some information on how to do with the library.   You really should have opened your own question this one is for 3.5 so its really not related to yours.    If you need anymore help let me know I have some tutorials on youtube floating around as well.